# How to download online videos

Tags: video, video-streaming, video-encoding

I have very low bandwidth available on my network. I don't want to watch the video online again and again. Instead I want to download the video for later use. I can download Youtube videos with some online downloaders i.e. With savevid.com, file2hd.com. To download video from this website(ooyala), I have used netvideohunter plugin for firefox, Internet download manager and many other things but failed to download video from OOYALA player.

I was trying to download this video - http://www.startv.in/episodes/hatim-defeats-kaala-saaya/57838

Someone told me that they(ooyala) provides their videos in fragments with different bitrates for each fragment.
Can Someone tell me what to do to download videos from ooyala player.

Comment: Have you tried IDM (internet download manager)??

Comment: which browser you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

With [Jdownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) you can do it and choose resolution, video quality, sound quality and format.

Comment: Is it able to download OOYALA Videos, I tried, but failed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Internet Download Manager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/) (IDM). It is the best solution for any kind of video downloading. Try it, I'm sure you will like it.